# WP MU: Using pages from main site in other sites’ menus

Tags: menus, multisite

Is it possible to use pages created on the main site in other sites’ menus?

For example it would be excellent if all pages from the main site not only appear in the Custom menu section (Appearance > Menus) of the main site but also on all other sites' menu sections when pages are searched.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static link in the WP Nav menu. Is this not enough, then it is possible to create the post inside the multisite install with the function `wp_insert_post()`. But this create all post in all sites in the network. It give also plugins for this to copy the page in other sites, like Mulitpost MU (http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/multipost-mu/).

[image]

Comment: The question is about pages but you answered for posts. Is there anything we can do for pages as well?

Comment: Why not; pages are not really different from posts, only another type in the same table.

Comment: I think the menu option is called "Custom Link" but that is the easiest way to just add a link from outside that WordPress install.